# Adding Current time to filename of image in php

Tags: php

I want to add current time to Image file name while saving into folder.

For example: `4.02PMrose.jpeg`

My attempt:

```
<?php

$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$location = "photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

Comment: So start writing code.

Comment: Take a look at [date/time formatting examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-examples), then simply append/prepend the date onto your filename.

Comment: You got a working answer.  With that said, having multiple '.' in a filename is a bad idea, and can easily lead to web exploits.  You should actively suppress/avoid files from webspace with more than one '.' in the name.  If you really want to do this, use underscores or dashes.  Also most people who do this would append the date to the end of the file name, rather than the beginning, so that related files are easier to find with basic sortation.

Comment: What has `addslashes` to do with the question? And if I may ask: What is the purpose of adding the current time to the file? The time is normally stored *with* the filename in the filesystem, file-uploads have the file-time of the upload automatically on most systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could use date function of php. It have two arguments

```
$name = date("h.iA")."Rose.png";
```

[php date function reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the 'time ()' function because it guarantees you a unique file name so avoiding conflicts between loads!

However here is the program you are asking for!

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"];
// basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;

// further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
$name = date("h.iA") . basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"]);

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

For more information, please refer to the manual page.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php